# Meteor Routing Templates

Tags: node.js, meteor

I am creating my fist meteor project I am just wondering why i have to keep importing each js file that imports the html page where as in the tutorials he doesn't import anything I just seem to know about the template.

```
//Import templates
import '../../ui/layouts/homelayout.js';
import '../../ui/layouts/mainlayout.js';
import '../../ui/layouts/recipes/recipe-book.js';
import '../../ui/layouts/recipes/RecipeSingle.js';



if (Meteor.isClient){
    Accounts.onLogin(function () {
        FlowRouter.go('recipe-book');
    });

    Accounts.onLogout(function () {
        FlowRouter.go('home');
    });
}


FlowRouter.triggers.enter([function(context, redirect){
    if(!Meteor.userId()){
        FlowRouter.go('home');
     }
}]);
//Route Definitions 
FlowRouter.route('/',{
     name: 'home',
     action() {
        if(Meteor.userId()){
            FlowRouter.go('recipe-book');
        }
        BlazeLayout.render('HomeLayout');
     }
});

FlowRouter.route('/recipe-book',{

     name: 'recipe-book',
     action() {
        BlazeLayout.render('MainLayout', {
            main: 'Recipes'
        });
     }
});

FlowRouter.route('/recipe/:id',{
     name: 'recipeSingle',
     action() {
        BlazeLayout.render('MainLayout', {
            main: 'RecipeSingle'
        });
     }
});

FlowRouter.route('/menu',{
     name: 'menu',
     action() {
        BlazeLayout.render('MainLayout', {
            main: 'Menu'
        });
     }
});
```

Comment: Have a look js file import html file. https://github.com/meteor/simple-todos/commit/81b442e117eb61469eef1b783552820aad769b08#diff-e9c5c2f9a09a70d419562a62d043007eR3

Comment: Hey thanks for the help